# How to put more value in not equal to condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table **test** in that deviceid column is there.

and my query is this

```
SELECT s.group_id,
       s.group_name,
       da.deviceid,
       da.digitaladdress,
       da.status,
       dt.digitaladdressdesc,
       dt.address_enable
FROM   OACT_TBL_DEVICES d,
       OMM_TBL_ACCOUNT_GROUPS g,
       OMM_TBL_GROUPS s,
       OACT_TBL_DIGITAL_ADDRESSES da,
       OACT_TBL_DIGITAL_ADDRESS_TYPE dt,
       test t
WHERE  s.group_id = '1'
       AND s.group_id = g.group_id
       AND g.accountid = d.accountid
       AND d.deviceid = da.deviceid
       AND d.deviceid <> t.DeviceId
       AND s.GROUP_NAME = t.GroupName
       AND da.digitaladdresstype = dt.digitaladdresstype
```

I know this query is not right but my main problem is that  deviceid I have in **test** table I have to exclude all those deviceid in this query..
So can we put more than one value in '<>' condition?
Or any other way is doing to exclude all my deviceid value with **test** table from this query output.
Please Help me .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As with lots of things in SQL, there are many ways you could do this - a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with NULL check, a `NOT IN` statement, or a `NOT EXISTS`.

Which works best is situation and user dependant - here's an example for the NOT EXISTS option:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM   test
                WHERE  test.DeviceID = d.DeviceID)
```

The NOT IN choice:

```
AND d.deviceid NOT IN (SELECT DeviceID 
                       FROM Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND D.deviceid NOT IN( SELECT deviceid from test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      s.group_id
    , s.group_name
    , da.deviceid
    , da.digitaladdress
    , da.[status]
    , dt.digitaladdressdesc
    , dt.address_enable
FROM dbo.OACT_TBL_DEVICES d
JOIN dbo.OMM_TBL_ACCOUNT_GROUPS g ON g.accountid = d.accountid
JOIN dbo.OMM_TBL_GROUPS s ON s.group_id = g.group_id
JOIN dbo.OACT_TBL_DIGITAL_ADDRESSES da ON d.deviceid = da.deviceid
JOIN dbo.OACT_TBL_DIGITAL_ADDRESS_TYPE dt ON da.digitaladdresstype = dt.digitaladdresstype
WHERE s.group_id = '1'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.test t
        WHERE t.deviceid = d.deviceid
    )
```

Comment: Thanx every one..Your all suggestion really helped me a lot and I got the idea to solve my problem.